# Adding subsubsection to smoothtree outertheme

Tags: beamer, formatting

I would like to make the name of the subsubsection appear in the presentation.
Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw} 
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,pxfonts,eulervm,xspace}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\useinnertheme{rounded}
\useoutertheme{smoothtree}
\usepackage{geometry}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{10cm}
\oddsidemargin = -1.8cm
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\setcounter{framenumber}{-1}
\marginparwidth = -12pt
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\subsection{Propiedades Eléctricas}
\subsubsection{Análisis de Impedancia}
\begin{frame}
Hola
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

What I got is [image]

But I would like:
[image]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The definition of the `smoothtree` headline can be found in `beamerouterthemesmoothtree.sty`. In the code below you can find an example on how to incorporate the `subsubsection`. In case you want a perfect copy of your original design, you have still have to incoporate the shading stuff.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Warsaw} 
\useoutertheme{smoothtree}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.125ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.125ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
        \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}%
        \hskip6pt\insertsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.125ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{subsection in head/foot}
        \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}%
        \hskip12pt\insertsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.125ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.3cm,rightskip=.3cm plus1fil]{section in head/foot}
        \usebeamerfont{subsubsection in head/foot}%
        \hskip18pt\insertsubsubsectionhead
    \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\title{test}

\begin{document}
\section{blub}
\subsection{Propiedades Elctricas}
\subsubsection{Anlisis de Impedancia}
\begin{frame}{frametitle}{framesubtitle}
Hola
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]